# Assign Priority for Callable type threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, runnable, callable

I am working on Threads task, which required to assign priorities for callable threads.

here is my code.

```
public void processURL(String[] synchronous, String[] asynchronous) {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREADS);
    for (int i = 0; i < asynchronous.length; i++) {
        es.execute(new TaskAsyn("Asynchronous Task: " + i, asynchronous[i],
                waiting));
    }

    List<Future<ToStore>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<ToStore>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < synchronous.length; i++) {
        Future<ToStore> future = es.submit(new TaskSynch(
                "synchronous Task: " + i, synchronous[i], waiting));
        futures.add(future);
    }

    for (Future<ToStore> future : futures) {
        try {
            ToStore s = future.get();
            // TODO
            System.out.println("Synchronous Task: " + s.getUrl()
                    + " has finished.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("here");
}
```

synchronous being executed in callable threads to get results in future.
asynchronous being executed in runnable threads.

I can make asynchronous callable threads as well;not the point, so my only problem how to make `ExecuterService` to be assigned threads with priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instantiate you Executor with a custom thread factory.

```
public class MyThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
   public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
     Thread t =  new Thread(r);
     t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY); //Or whatever priority
     return t;
   }
 }

ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREADS,new MyThreadFactory());
```